# How to run function over and over again with different parameters

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have a function which countsdown a time. It takes in two paramaters - minutes,seconds.

At first it should count down some time for example 60 seconds and then then when the time is at 0:00 it should start the function again but with different parameters for example 30 seconds. And after it is equal 0 it should start the same function with 60 seconds and so on until the infinity or I change function variable working equals to false.

Here is my code of what I have tried so far:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="start">start counting<div>
  <script>
  var count = 1000;
var working = true; 
var running = false;
                // year, month, day, hour, min, sec
var date = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 0, 02);

var newInterval;
var newBreak;
//  alert(date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
$('#start').click(function(){
  if(working){
    countDown(0,6);
    working = false;
  } else if(!working) {
    countDown(0,25);
    working = true;
  }
  
  
});

function countDown(minutes, seconds){
   date.setMinutes(minutes);
   date.setSeconds(seconds);
   var breaker = setInterval(function(){
   date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() - 1);
   if(date.getMinutes()== 0 && date.getSeconds() ==0){
      clearInterval(breaker);
     alert("aaaa?");
   }
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = date.getMinutes() +":"+ date.getSeconds(); 
  },1000);

}


  </script>
```

How do i make the countDown function to run over and over again with the different parameters. So the end result would be after 1 minute is finished run 30 seconds countdown, after 30 seconds are finished run 1 minute countdown.

Comment: Use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to put the full **runnable** example *in* the question, rather than using off-site resources.

Comment: Not certain what Question is?

Comment: edited the code snippet, and added the question.

Comment: The result at stacksnippets does not appear to render corresponding to seconds selected?

Comment: Next time please try to reduce to a [mcve] and put the relevant bits in the relevant parts of the snippet, to make it easy for people to see and modify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `countDown` accept a callback or return a promise, then when it finishes call the callback or resolve the promise. That lets the calling code then start the next countdown.

Using a promise:

```
function countDown(minutes, seconds) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { // <====
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    var breaker = setInterval(function() {
      date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() - 1);
      if (date.getMinutes() == 0 && date.getSeconds() == 0) {
        clearInterval(breaker);
        resolve();                       // <====
      }
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
$('#start').click(function() {
  countDown(0, 6).then(function() {  // <====
    countDown(0, 25);                // <====
  });                                // <====
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var count = 1000;
var working = true;
var running = false;
// year, month, day, hour, min, sec
var date = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 0, 02);
var breakTime = document.getElementById("break").innerHTML = 5;
var intervalTime = document.getElementById("timeInterval").innerHTML = 25;
var newInterval;
var newBreak;
//  alert(date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
$('#start').click(function() {
  countDown(0, 6).then(function() {  // <====
    countDown(0, 25);                // <====
  });                                // <====
});

function countDown(minutes, seconds) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { // <====
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    var breaker = setInterval(function() {
      date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() - 1);
      if (date.getMinutes() == 0 && date.getSeconds() == 0) {
        clearInterval(breaker);
        resolve();                       // <====
      }
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

$(".incrementTime").click(function() {
  newInterval = $('#timeInterval').text(parseInt($('#timeInterval').text()) + 1);
});
$(".decrementTime").click(function() {
  newInterval = $('#timeInterval').text(parseInt($('#timeInterval').text()) - 1);
});

$(".incrementBreak").click(function() {
  newBreak = $('#break').text(parseInt($('#break').text()) + 1);
});
$(".decrementBreak").click(function() {
  newBreak = $('#break').text(parseInt($('#break').text()) - 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrementBreak">-</button>
    <span id="break">5</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default incrementBreak">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrementTime">-</button>
    <span id="timeInterval">25</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default incrementTime">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>

</div>
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="start">start counting
  <div>
```

Using a callback:

```
function countDown(minutes, seconds, callback) {
  // --------------------------------^
  date.setMinutes(minutes);
  date.setSeconds(seconds);
  var breaker = setInterval(function() {
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() - 1);
    if (date.getMinutes() == 0 && date.getSeconds() == 0) {
      clearInterval(breaker);
      if (callback) {           // <====
        callback();             // <====
      }                         // <====
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Usage:

```
$('#start').click(function() {
  countDown(0, 6, function() {  // <====
    countDown(0, 25);           // <====
  });                           // <====
});
```

Or, again, you can use promises.

Live Example:

```js
var count = 1000;
var working = true;
var running = false;
// year, month, day, hour, min, sec
var date = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 0, 02);
var breakTime = document.getElementById("break").innerHTML = 5;
var intervalTime = document.getElementById("timeInterval").innerHTML = 25;
var newInterval;
var newBreak;
//  alert(date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
$('#start').click(function() {
  countDown(0, 6, function() {  // <====
    countDown(0, 25);           // <====
  });                           // <====
});

function countDown(minutes, seconds, callback) {
  // --------------------------------^
  date.setMinutes(minutes);
  date.setSeconds(seconds);
  var breaker = setInterval(function() {
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() - 1);
    if (date.getMinutes() == 0 && date.getSeconds() == 0) {
      clearInterval(breaker);
      if (callback) {           // <====
        callback();             // <====
      }                         // <====
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
  }, 1000);
}

$(".incrementTime").click(function() {
  newInterval = $('#timeInterval').text(parseInt($('#timeInterval').text()) + 1);
});
$(".decrementTime").click(function() {
  newInterval = $('#timeInterval').text(parseInt($('#timeInterval').text()) - 1);
});

$(".incrementBreak").click(function() {
  newBreak = $('#break').text(parseInt($('#break').text()) + 1);
});
$(".decrementBreak").click(function() {
  newBreak = $('#break').text(parseInt($('#break').text()) - 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrementBreak">-</button>
    <span id="break">5</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default incrementBreak">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrementTime">-</button>
    <span id="timeInterval">25</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default incrementTime">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>

</div>
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="start">start counting
  <div>
```